# Error during installation of TeXLive 2012 in Fedora

Tags: errors, installing, texlive, linux

I am facing problems while trying to install TeXLive 2012 on fedora. I did the following-

1. Unzipped the package.
2. Navigated to the location of `install-tl`.
3. Typed in `./install-tl`

I got the following message

```
Can't locate Digest/MD5.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ./tlpkg /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 199.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 199.
Compilation failed in require at ./install-tl line 53.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./install-tl line 53.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do to I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Try installing `perl-Tk` and `perl-Digest-MD5` first with `yum install perl-Tk perl-Digest-MD5`, then try the TeX Live installer again. `:)`

Comment: Use the packages provided by Fedora. Fedora 18 ships TeXlive 2012 out of the box, fully integrated with the system.

Comment: @vonbrand True, but if you want a 'vanilla' install (say so you have `tlmgr` available to update every day), then I'd image the issue _is_ the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this guide; I only tested it on Fedora before writing the article (but that is obviously enough here): http://latex-community.org/component/content/article/66-latex-distributions-texlive/466-texlive-linux